# How to make interpolation and contour for recording distances on images?

Tags: distance, interpolation, contour

I have a question about interpolation and contours.

In the images from the animal observation cameras, we would estimate the distance from the camera to the animal. In theory, we had the idea of placing every 5 metres from the camera 3 stick.

[image: Image from trail camera]

In Qgis we imported an image and created "point.shp" (data: x, y and z). The "z" values would be the distance, not the height. We have tried several ways but everything is always distorted

[image: Image with points (data: x,y,z]

[image: Image, point and contours]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking to create a depth map.  Do you have stereo pairs of images?  Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_map) for general information on depth maps.  [Here](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=9776.0) for information on depth map from cameras.  And [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html.) for a Python solution.

Then create contours from your depth map.

Comment: We do not have stereo pairs of images.

Comment: Maybe a solution here:  https://www.scantips.com/lights/subjectdistance.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but we will have thousands of images to look at and estimate the distances from the camera to the animal, so we need a more simple method like a heatmap.